# How to get id from windowPopup button

Tags: android, android-layout

I need somebody help me,  need to know how to get button'id from windowPopup for the activity show the correct layout.

This is the code that I use,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.pop_broker:
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_broker);
                    break;
                case R.id.pop_carrier:
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_carrier);
                    break;
                case R.id.pop_driver:
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_driver);
                    break;
                case R.id.pop_dispatcher:
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_dispatcher);
                    break;
                case R.id.pop_owner:
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_owner_operator);
                    break;
            }
        }
        };

    v.findViewById(R.id.pop_carrier).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    v.findViewById(R.id.pop_driver).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    v.findViewById(R.id.pop_dispatcher).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    v.findViewById(R.id.pop_owner).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    v.findViewById(R.id.pop_broker).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Comment: what do you mean by windowPopup?

Comment: windowPopup is that I used for create a popup or emergen window